# Unable to extract data from Firebase records

Tags: list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, app-inventor

I am working with AppInventor. I have 2 records in firebase as given in the pic below

[image]

I am trying to read the data on screen initialization and store the specific data in some global variables. Please check the blocks below

[image]

However, whenever the for loop runs, the GetValue (ProductDesc) function is running first and then the (ProductName). Also, I am not able to store the data in the list (global productDesc) and (global productTitle)

I don’t know where I am making the mistake. Would really appreciate someones help.